# Capitalized column name to retrieve data in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

**Overview:**

I have this table called `User`

[image]

Notice that most of the column names are on **StudlyCaps** like every word has been capitalized.

Now, one of the problem that I've been experiencing is of course when logging in. It's mostly like Laravel doesn't like capitalized column names and such.

Here's my `User Model` I'll just put the relevant parts regarding on my problem.

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $primaryKey = "UserID";
    protected $fillable = array('Username', 'Password', 'Active');
    protected $table = 'Users';
}
```

And here's my method where the user starts to log in.

```
public function postLogin() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        )
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // Redirect
    } else {

        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'Username' => Input::get('username'),
            'Password' => Input::get('password'),
            'Active'   => 1 
        ));

        if ($auth) {
            return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
        } else {
            return  Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('global', 'Username/Password wrong, or account not activated');
        }
    }
    // Redirect
}
```

And here goes my error, it always say `Username/Password wrong, or account not activated.`

[image]

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: why can't you just rename the column names to underscore case?

Comment: Also, you should just use `id` instead of `UserID` to be consistent with the Laravel approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its best to rename all your columns 'snake_case' style. **A)** this will work nicely with Laravel and **B)** it's good practice to keep all your database table names and columns etc the same.